# JavaFx BarChart Legend Color

Tags: javafx-2

I know that I can set set color of the legend Item with this code:

`for (Node n : chart.lookupAll(".bar-legend-symbol.default-color0")) {
    n.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + "red"+ ";");
       }`

But it only works, when I first add the data to the chart an then the chart to the scene.
Like this:

```
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
XYChart.Data<String, Number>bar = new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("test", 120);
series.getData().add(bar);

chart.getData().add(series);

chartFxPanel.setScene(new Scene(chart));

for (Node n : chart.lookupAll(".bar-legend-symbol.default-color0")) {
    n.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + "red"+ ";");
   }
```

But I want to add the data to the chart after the chart has been added to the scene. If I do this it does not change the color of the legend Item:

```
final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
XYChart.Data<String, Number>bar = new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("test", 120);
series.getData().add(bar);


chartFxPanel.setScene(new Scene(chart));
chart.getData().add(series);


for (Node n : chart.lookupAll(".bar-legend-symbol.default-color0")) {
    n.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + "red"+ ";");
   }
```

How can I change then the color of the legend item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely it will work if you wrap your lookup/setStyle code in a [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html) call (or worst case, delay it using a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) like this [example](https://gist.github.com/2129306)).  Those constructs give the JavaFX system a chance to process and style the data item change on the next pulse so that you can subsequently override it.

Any reason why you can't just customize the style using a css stylesheet rather than using a java code lookup? That is, use similar techniques as outlined in the [JavaFX chart styling guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm).  Then you wouldn't need to deal with lookup timing related issues, which would seem preferable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need a dynamic chart, so that I can`t use a fix number of color for the bars.